# zend acl with extra url paramaters

Tags: php, zend-framework, acl

Ok, I am working on a basic blog concept as some practice with Zend Framework.

I am using Zend 1.11

```
<?php

class App_Controller_Plugin_Acl extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        // resources

        $acl = new Zend_Acl();

        $acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('guest'));
        $acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('free'), 'guest');
        $acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('paid'), 'free');
        $acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('admin'), 'paid');


        $acl->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('index'));
        $acl->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('auth'));
        $acl->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('error'));
        $acl->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('user'));
        $acl->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('page'));
        $acl->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('blog'));
        $acl->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('admin'));

        // set up the access rules
        // everyone has full access to index, error and auth

        $acl->allow(null, array('index', 'error', 'auth', 'blog', 'page'));
        $acl->allow('guest', array('index', 'error', 'auth', 'blog', 'page'));
        $acl->allow('admin', null);


        // a guest can only read content and login
        // $acl->deny('guest', 'blog', 'comment');


        // free users can access the user panel
        $acl->allow('free', 'user');

        // cms users can also work with content
        //$acl->allow('user', 'page', array('list', 'create', 'edit', 'delete'));

        // administrators can do anything
        $acl->allow('admin', null);


        // load the auth instance
        $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();

        // set a default role of guest
        if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
            $identity = $auth->getIdentity();
            $role = strtolower($identity->role);
        } else{
            $role = 'guest';
        }

        // check the request
        $controller = $request->controller;
        $action = $request->action;

        // verify they have permission
        if (!$acl->isAllowed($role, $controller, $action)) {
            if ($role == 'guest') {
                $request->setControllerName('auth');
                $request->setActionName('login');
            } else {
                $request->setControllerName('error');
                $request->setActionName('noauth');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And so, I want to have a URL to access posts similar to `whatever.com/blog/post/DATE/TITLE/`

I am logged in as an admin, and I can view `whatever.com/blog/post/` with no problems,
but if I put in any other parameters, it redirects me to the index/index...

What is going wrong?!! I have no idea where the error could be, so idk what code I should post to show you where I may have made an error....

EDIT my application.ini

```
; ------------------------------------------------------
[production]
; ------------------------------------------------------
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts"
resources.frontController.plugins.acl = "App_Controller_Plugin_Acl"
resources.view.helperPath.App_View_Helper_ = "App/View/Helper/"

resources.db.adapter = PDO_MYSQL
resources.db.params.host = localhost
resources.db.params.username = root
resources.db.params.password =
resources.db.params.dbname = zendcasts

autoloaderNamespaces.app = App_
```

My Auth is ok, I can log in ok, and my identity stores the correct info....

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any problems in Acl class. I think problem should search in the other places. First I would like to see application.ini. And then we try make a decision what to do. If it is possible send me your code or publish aplication.ini here.

Comment: I edited my post to include my application.ini .. but i don't see any problem there either.. I thought maybe the router is action funny?

Comment: The only thing I can imagine is the settings of mod_rewrite on your server or wrong config of a .htaccess